# Ways to support manually executed tests? (that can be used on a Mac)

Tags: macos, testing

Are there any tools that can be used on a Mac to support manually executed tests? I have a number of tests that I'm executing manually and which I'm currently documenting using merely a plain text file. "Tools" can be interpreted rather loosely here, anything that's a step up from the plain text file would be useful: a template for some suitable application, supporting AppleScript scripts, a web-based system, a full-blown application ...

Some things that would be great to have better support for (see also the example below):

- Checking off each step while you're manually executing the test.
- Showing the next step(s) in a small window that is always kept in front of all other windows.
- Automatically updating the 'last tested' and 'using svn revision' info.
- Keeping a record of all previous testing rounds (not just the last one).
- ...

Any suggestions for any such "tools" that can be used on a Mac?

---

An example (faked) entry from the plain text file to give you a better idea of what I'm looking for:

```
- Check that exported web pages render properly in Safari.
  Last tested: 2010-03-24
  Using SVN revision: 1000

  Steps:
  - Open a new document.
  - Add some items to the document.
  - Export the document to a web page "Test.html" in a new folder "Export Test"
    on the Desktop.
  - Open the web page in Safari, script:
      tell application "Finder"
        open file "Test.html" of folder "Export Test" of desktop
      end tell

  Expected results:
  - The web page should appear properly with all items shown.

  Clean up steps:
  - Remove the folder "Export Test" from the Desktop.
```

( Note: for those unaware, the snippet of AppleScript in the above can be executed from most text editing applications through the Services menu by selecting the snippet and using: the application menu > Services > Script Editor > Run as AppleScript. This is quite useful to automate some steps for tests that are difficult to automate as a whole. )

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TestLink](http://blog.testlink.org/) - it's a PHP app that you should be able get get working on a Mac easily enough, and will do most of the things you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It does look like an interesting tool. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be actively maintained: most of the tab links at the top of the page don't work, and the latest "updated version" post in the blog dates back to 2008.

Comment: Hmm, I have to admit I hadn't looked at Testlink for a while; I noticed that the daily builds of the code are still happening, at least.  Another tool that might be worth a look is Testopia (http://www.mozilla.org/projects/testopia/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into our test management tool [TestRail](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/), as it does most of what you mentioned. TestRail is a PHP application (web-based) and can be installed on almost any system.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks like a great tool. Should perhaps have added 'free' as an additional requirement though. I don't have 199 EUR to spare on this at the moment ;)